# Date Picker Validation Start Date

Tags: validation, plsql, datepicker, oracle-apex

I am new to the environment and need help writing a validation statement in APEX.

I have a Start Date and End Date field on a page with a Date Picker Type.

The End Date validation has already been set  ( end date must be equal to or greater than start date )

Now I need to implement this validation for start date:

- User should be able to choose either the current date (today) or a future date.

Is there a way to disable previous days on Apex? Or would I need to write a validation statement? If so, what validation statement could I use?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the settings for the date picker, specifically the minimum date.

[image]

Use the help to work out exactly what you need. APEX will then handle the validations for you.